# Mongoose: find with a limit and notify if last chunk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to build a "load more" function that loads to page only a certain amount of documents on each load, and that will disappear once there are no more docs to load.

So first of all I added a `limit` option (10 docs per chuck) to the mongoose query. And added a check to whether the limit set (10) equals the amount of docs received, but still, if it happens to be that there are 100 docs at one time, the tenth chuck will be equal to the limit set, but it WILL be the last chuck.

Is there any other option in mongoose to `bool` whether the results received are the last for that specific query?

**Edit:** I could ofcourse query without any limit and check whether I'm responding with the last chunk but I believe that would be costy and that there's probably a native solution.

On second thought, I could limit a `x+1` more than the limit I actually need and that way make sure manually by skipping just `x` every time. Any thing last hacky?

Comment: fwiw, if this is for a continuous stream of documents you might not want the "load more" link to disappear. If new documents are added matching your query, it may still be valid to try to "load more" and you could provide some UI feedback if there are no new documents found.